# openCL stack location (recursion)

Tags: stack, opencl

I'm doing a quicksort (recursiv) with openCL on one thread and I got some issues. The openCL compilator will return an error if i try to compile my code for my intel cpu ("recursion detected" with openCL 2.0) but it compiles and works on my nvidia 950M(openCL 1.2) only for few recursion calls.

After some investigations, i've found that the "OUT_OF_MEMORY" error appends when my stack was bigger than 32Ko, so I've two questions for you expers ;)

*First one* : Why the hell can I use recursivity on openCL 1.2 devices and not on openCL 2.0 devices ? (when openCL 1.2 isn't supposed to support recursion).

*Second one* : The private memory can't be bigger than 32Ko (like the max size of my stack). So, is my stack stored in my private memory ? Or just in anothe location with the same space ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recursion is not allowed in OpenCL kernels (see section "6.9 Restrictions" sub-section i: "Recursion is not supported"). The fact it works (partially) in one of your devices is a bug.

Solution: recode your kernel to use iteration instead of recursion.

Comment: In shading languages that don't allow recursion, I usually implement it [using macro expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77470186/975097) when the maximum depth of recursion is known at compile-time. This should be possible in OpenCL as well.